# Are these two generator expressions doing the same thing?

Tags: python, generator-expression

Assuming that there is a list to work on, I am not sure whether these two lines of code have the same return values:

```
sum(lst[i] for i in lst[:-1] if lst[i]<0)

sum(lst[i] for i in range(len(lst)-1) if lst[i]<0)
```

Furthermore, could I have replaced `sum(lst[i]...` with `sum(i...` and still get the exact same result?

Comment: No, the first uses `i` incorrectly, so they are not equivalent. The first won't work.

Comment: Also, you have *generator expressions*, not list comprehensions. No list is created.

Comment: "I am not sure whether these two lines of code have the same return values" Why don't you try to run both and see for yourself?

Answer (score 0):

In the first you are looping over the elements of `lst`; do **not** use those values as an index. Instead, just use the values directly:

```
sum(elem for elem in lst[:-1] if elem < 0)
```

I renamed `i` to `elem` to make this clearer; now it the equivalent of your second version, where you use indices generated by `range()`.

When you already have a sequence, and need to iterate over the values, there rarely is a need to use `range()` to produce indices instead.